# Xcode - preventing autoformat errors

Tags: c++, xcode, format

I use Xcode a lot - for cross platform projects. Sometimes, when I press Cmd-A Ctrl-I (auto-indent everything), it will mis-indent after encountering a line like:

```
std::cout << something;
```

Instead of this:

```
if(some_condition()) {
    std::cout << something;
}
other_things();
```

It will do this:

```
if(some_condition()) {
    std::cout << something;
    }
    other_things();
```

I cannot find any consistency as to when the mistake will be made, so providing an MCSE is not an easy task.

I have found one workaround (supplied as an answer) but if there is a better way I'd love to know!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The confusion in the auto-formatter seems to be related to the interpreter seeing `x << y` as an expression with no left hand side, which of course it would be if `x` were anything other than an `ostream`.

The formatting error goes away if you replace this:

```
if(some_condition()) {
    std::cout << something;
    }
```

with this:

```
if(some_condition()) {
    auto& os = std::cout << something;
    // but note we now get a warning about an unused variable
}
```

or this:

```
if(some_condition()) {
    void(std::cout << something);
    // deliberately discard the returned ostream&
}
```

Neither is pretty and both are likely to prompt future maintainers (particularly if they're using netbeans, codeblocks, vi, emacs or eclipse) to wonder what on earth my intent was.

Answer (score 0):

I always do this and it makes me happy.

First do Cmd + A

THen do Cmd + [  like 5-10 times

Then I do Ctrl + I, it indents properly every time.

Comment: oh... my... god... well, I'll give it a try. Thanks.